# SSRS Matrix Not Sorting

Tags: reporting-services

I need to display an SSRS report that displays values per month with a custom display order but I cant get it to work. In my tablix properties I have the following sort order as an expression (sorted a-z):

```
 =Switch(
 Fields!Month.Value = "January", 10,
 Fields!Month.Value = "February", 11,
 Fields!Month.Value = "March", 12,
 Fields!Month.Value = "April", 1,
 Fields!Month.Value = "May", 2,
 Fields!Month.Value = "June", 3,
 Fields!Month.Value = "July", 4,
 Fields!Month.Value = "August", 5,
 Fields!Month.Value = "September", 6,
 Fields!Month.Value = "October", 7,
 Fields!Month.Value = "November", 8,
 Fields!Month.Value = "December", 9)
```

If I also put the expression as an extra column for testing it returns the expected results, but doesn't sort appropriately. Is there something obvious that I'm missing? It needs to display April first, and then the following months in order.

[image]

**Edit**

I tried changing the switch statement to return a letter instead of an int, but still no luck.

Comment: It appears that your sort expression is being evaluated as a string.

Comment: What is providing the month rows e.g. January?  Presumably it is a Row Group.  The properties of that Group are where you need to set the Sort Order.

Comment: @MikeHoney that worked like a charm...I was setting the sort order on the tablix, which was being overridden by the sort order on the row group. Can you edit your comment as an answer so I can accept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is providing the month rows e.g. January? Presumably it is a Row Group. The properties of that Group are where you need to set the Sort Order.